# How can I download attachments from a Rally workitem using JAVA Rest API?

Tags: java, rest, attachment, rally

I couldn't find a working example for that.
I tried below from [How do I read the attachment content on a Defect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550864/how-do-i-read-the-attachment-content-on-a-defect)

but I am getting a `ClasscastException` as a `JsonObject` can't be cast to `JsonArray` for

`JsonArray attachmentsJsonArray = existUserStoryJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Attachments");`

```
QueryRequest  existUserStoryRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
existUserStoryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name","Attachments"));
existUserStoryRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", existStoryFormattedID));
QueryResponse userStoryQueryResponse = restApi.query(existUserStoryRequest);
JsonObject existUserStoryJsonObject = userStoryQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
String existUserStoryRef = userStoryQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").toString();
JsonArray attachmentsJsonArray = existUserStoryJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("Attachments");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some minor updates needed to get the code referenced in the old answer to work with CA Agile Central Webservices v2.0. You can find a modified version of that example here:

https://github.com/markwilliams970/rally-java-rest-apps/blob/master/AttachmentDownloadFromStory.java

That includes the WSAPI v2.0 updates.